# FFMpeg errors out when no subtitle exists

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert .mkv to .mp4 using ffmpeg and during conversion I am also trying to burn the subtitles if they exist. Here's the command line. This is a script:

```
$PGMNAME -i "$1" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -strict -2 -vf subtitles="$1"  "$BASEPATH/$FILENAME.mp4"
```

`"$1"` is the original file which is a .mkv file containing (or not and this is the problem) a subtitle. With the above I am getting the following errors:

```
Unable to locate subtitle stream file.mkv
```

and

```
Error initializing filter 'subtitles'
```

These are tv shows downloaded Over The Air. It's unknown which one's contain subtitles. How can I rewrite the command so that I don't get the `Unable to locate subtitle stream file.mkv` error?

Comment: You don't need `-strict -2` because: 1) you're stream copying the audio, and 2) even if you were encoding with the native FFmpeg AAC encoder only outdated builds need that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ffprobe` to determine if there is a subtitle stream. If there are any then use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter.

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s:0 -show_entries stream=codec_type -of csv=p=0 input.mkv
```

- If there are subtitles it will output `subtitle`.
- If there are no subtitles it will output nothing.

Comment: Also, a command of the form `ffmpeg -i in -c copy ... -map -0:s -f nut - && ffmpeg -i - -vf subtitles=in out.mp4 || ffmpeg -i in out.mp4`